# Winforms, handling simultaneous events, async/await or Task.Run()

Tags: multithreading, winforms, async-await, concurrency, simultaneous

I'm developing a Net6 Windows Form application
This application is connected with SignalR to a server, and server send message to it.
Moreover the application monitors some folders with FileSystemWatcher.

Application waits and when events occur (signalR or when a file is created) the dedicated methods are executed. These methods for example write records to a database or call web apis, wait for response and write other files.
Nothing of expensive for CPU.

The form UI is very poor, there are few controls, just a few buttons and a textbox connected to serilog, so it is not important to update the UI.

All methods called by signalr events or FileSystemWather events are async/await.

I wonder what happens if multiple events happen at the same time or almost let's say (also from different sources, signalr calls or filesystemwatcher). Do each event runs in a separate task or there might be problems handling concurrent events?
I have to manage the events methods with Task.Run() or is it's enough the async/await ?

Thank you very much

Andrea

Comment: In this scenario, in any case, you have to offload all work to a worker *thread*, you cannot have any synchronous code that blocks the event handlers. You have very different ways to handle this: you can enqueue the worker methods (you say you have async stuff there). You most probably need to handle FSW events and SignalR events differently, not clear whether these *interconnect* somehow. Since you're targeting .NET6+ and you have some sort producer/consumer model, you may want to make use of [System.Threading.Channels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/channels)

Comment: Side note: handle exceptions carefully. No matter whether you have your own logging or validation in place (e.g., FluentValidation), don't throw. Go *procedural*, use a paradigm you may find in languages as F#, use a `Result` object model to handle exceptions

Comment: @Jimi thank you. FSW and SignalR are no interconnected but in the same moment can arrive a signalr request and also FSW event (file written in lan shared folder). At the moment  every folder watcher by FSW have a separated thread. Also SignalR is wrapped in a class and started using a thread: inside this class there are 4 methods that the server can call, these 4 methods are async. Do you think is better create a distinct thread every time one of this 4 methods is invoked? The frequency with which these methods are invoked is not high, and execution is fast (200-500ms). Thank you very much.

Comment: The implementation of this (apparently simple) mechanism, is more tightly coupled to the architecture of the application than one may initially think. But, the suggested `Channel<T>` implementation is really simple; it's thread-safe producer / consumer queue that uses a `ConcurrentQueue<T>` under the hood. You enqueue and operation (e.g., in an event handler), to offload work to a *waiter* method that reads the queue asynchronously and, when something becomes available, gets the value / action from the queue. Then it would probably call a worker method that processes the data

Comment: If you need to update the UI or perform logging / validation / all of the above, you can use Progress<T> delegates that are created in the, e.g., UI / logger / validator Thread(s). The delegate(s) only handle processed data and put(s) it where it belongs -- Note that the Writer method that enqueues the data / action (`TryWrite()` or `WriteAsync( )`) always operates synchronously. so you just enqueue *raw data* or an action delegate and nothing else. Event handlers cannot be blocked by synchronous code -- The FSW probably needs a Buffer larger than the default (at least double it)

Comment: See: [An Introduction to System.Threading.Channels](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/an-introduction-to-system-threading-channels/) (Stephen Toub actually wrote Channel<T>, so he's competent in this matter :)